# What are the scrolling limits of a Virtual Tree View?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

How can I get the max scroll for the X and Y in virtualstringtree during onchange event?

Comment: Why do you mention OnChange? Are you asking because you already have some method of getting the scrolling limits, but when you use it in OnChange, you get the wrong result? (If so, please describe the problem.) Or are you asking because you have no way of getting the limits yet, and the place you intend to use it once you have it happens to be that event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetTreeRect` method gives the dimensions in pixels of the entire tree, or the dimensions of the client area, whichever is larger. Note that if there are no columns configured, then the size of the tree can vary based on which nodes are displayed on the screen at the time — the scrolling width changes according to the widest nodes visible.

The `Bottom` and `Right` fields of that rectangle determine the scroll-bar range.